# How to count the length of a line in bash such that spaces for indentation are excluded?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I wish to enforce a rule that no line in a `python` code would be more than 80  characters in length. For this I count the length of the entire line in file using a bash script. However, I need to exclude the starting spaces used for indentation. I wish to start counting from where the first character is seen in the line, until the last character: e.g:

```
    this is an example line
```

length() needs to return (31-8=23) rather than 31.

How do I accomplish this using a `sed`, `awk`, or `grep` query?

Comment: That's not a very useful limitation, though, is it? If I indent 10 levels deep but use no more than 80 characters after indentation, I meet the requirement, but it's certainly not good style.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But this is to check code submitted by students programming for the first time. They need to learn good coding practices (lines more than 80 char should be broken using '\') but their projects are not so complicated that they will go more than ~3-4 levels of indentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ echo '    this is an example line' | awk '{gsub(/^ +/,""); print length}'
23
```

Explanation:

`gsub(/^ +/,"")` - In short replace starting space chars with null in current record/row/line.

- `^` asserts position at start of the string,
- space as char
- `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy),

Comment: Thank you for the response and the detailed explanation along with it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is less-known expr command variant:

```
a="        this is an example line"
```

Count spaces before:

```
$ expr match "$a" " *"
8
```

All string length:

```
$ expr length "$a" 
31
```

Length of useful characters:

```
$ expr length "$(echo $a)"
23
```

Answer (score 1):

With posix shell

```
a='        this is an example line'
echo "${#a}"
b="${a%%[^ ]*}"
echo "${#b}"
c="${a#$b*}"
echo "${#c}"
```

output

```
31
8
23
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed file.txt 's/^ *//' | sed 's/^\t*//' | wc -c
```